# Merge multiple mp4 (h264 + aac) videos into one frame without re-encoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, debian, mp4, h.264

I have four mp4 files with same length (1 minute each) , say 1.mp4, 2.mp4, 3.mp4 and 4.mp4. I want to merge these four videos into a single frame and create a mosaic of four videos; 1.mp4 at the top-left, 2.mp4 at the top-right, 3.mp4 at the bottom-left and 4.mp4 at the bottom-right.

I have tried the same using ffmpeg filter_complex.

> ffmpeg    -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4     -filter_complex "
>         nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];        [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,
>   scale=320x240 [upperleft];        [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240
>   [upperright];         [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
>         [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
>         [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];        [tmp1][upperright]
>   overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];      [tmp2][lowerleft]
>   overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];      [tmp3][lowerright]
>   overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240    "   output.mp4

But the problem is, ffmpeg re-encodes the video. The input videos already have h.264 + aac encoding, and the output video will have the same encoding. I would be running this code on a very low-power embedded Linux board which have only one core CPU. The board is taking almost 6x times of the file length to produce the output (i.e. 6 minutes in my case), and also consuming 100% of the CPU.

Is there any other way to do this, without re-encoding? I run the whole thing on Debian, so I can use any package you suggest.

Comment: "without re-encoding?" - Short answer: no.

Comment: You can't filter without encoding, but you can do this during playback instead. If that's an acceptable solution I can provide an answer (but it may have to wait until Sunday unless someone else provides an example).

Comment: As you need to decode, you could try using GPU for it. Or change your output to screen instead of file, then you do not need to encode ;-)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The users can play as well as download the files from a web portal. If they can view the mosaic during the playback from the portal, then if solves 50% of the problem. The other 50% would be solved if they can play the videos in mosaic after downloading.